# c++ Recursion addition, 4*x

Tags: c++, recursion

I have been trying to understand how to work on a function that returns the sum of a number like this: 1+2+3+4...4n  by using recursion

I tried different cases without success and I am wondering if there is any mathematical way to solve it and translate it into code. I know that if I were this function:

```
int MyFunction(int x) 
{
  if (x==0)
   return 0;
  else{
    return x+MyFunction(x-1);
  }
}
```

and I used x=3 it would return 1+2+3 which is equal to 6 but in my case, I want to do something similar but up to 4 times the number. For example if x=1 it will return 1+2+3+4 since 4(1)=4. Then what returns is the addition of those numbers which is equal to 10

I tried thinking about simply converting the x to 4*x

```
int MyFunction(int x) 
{
  if (x==0)
   return 0;
  else{
    return 4*x+MyFunction(x-1);
  }
}
```

of course this didn't work, I also tried thinking that since everything was the same but by a factor of 4 thus MyFunction(4(x-1)) but obviously I am not thinking of this correctly. I wanted suggestions at least to understand the math behind it and how to relate it to code

Comment: What is the return value of the function when `x==0`?

Comment: `MyFunction(4*x)`...

Comment: @NO_NAME   when x==0 returns 0 since 4(0)=0

Comment: @MarcGlisse the function has to calculate that, otherway I would just implement the number

Comment: No. You have a specific `if` statement giving special treatment for the case when `x==0`, and when `x==0` the function returns nothing. Or better yet, it's undefined what it's returning. The compiler probably gave you a warning about that, and you ignored it.

Comment: @Havenard  you are right I need to edit that, that was for another function

Comment: @Thevenin99 @Havenard Compiler may return `0` as a default value but this is a very bad practice to assume it would. It is confusing to other peoples reading the code and it makes the program less portable.

Comment: @NO_NAME thats right, it was supposed to be return 0, sorry I didnt mean to type {}, still wondering how to solve the problem in the question

Answer (score 1):

**nonrecursive solution**

The sum of the members of a finite arithmetic progression is called *an arithmetic series*. For example, consider the sum:

```
1 + 2 + 3 + ... 4n-1 + 4n
```

This sum can be found quickly by taking the number of terms being added (here 4n), multiplying by the sum of the first and last number in the progression (here 1 + 4n = 4n+1), and dividing by 2.

The formula you are looking for is:

```
sum = 2n(4n+1)
```

A possible implementation can be:

```
int MyFunction(int n) 
{
    assert(n>0);

    return 2*n*(4*n+1);
}
```

note: we do not checked a possible overflow

---

**recursive solution**

```
int recursive_sum(int k)
{
  return (k>0) ? k+recursive_sum(k-1) : 0;
}

int recursive_MyFunction(int n)
{
  assert(n>0);

  return recursive_sum(4*n);
}
```

---

**Check that both approaches give the same result**

```
#include <cassert>

int MyFunction(int n) { ... as before ...} 
int recursive_MyFunction(int n) { ... as before ...} 

int main()
{
  int n = 10; // whatever you want

  assert(recursive_MyFunction(n)==MyFunction(n));
}
```

Comment: is it possible to implement it in just one function? in this case in just the function int MyFunction( int x), instead of 2 functions

Comment: @Thevenin99 for the moment I have no idea, not sure it is possible.

Comment: Why would you want it as a single function? Of course it is possible, but the code will be worse by any reasonable criterion.